# Sending messages between class threads Python

Tags: python, multithreading, messaging

Does anybody know how I can send a variable (or get a variable) from threadOne to threadTwo in this code without using a global variable?  If not, how would I operate a global variable?  Just define it before both classes and use the global definition in the run function?

```
import threading

print "Press Escape to Quit"

class threadOne(threading.Thread): #I don't understand this or the next line
    def run(self):
        setup()

    def setup():
        print 'hello world - this is threadOne'


class threadTwo(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print 'ran'

threadOne().start()
threadTwo().start()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [queues](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) to send messages between threads in a thread safe way.

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: Do I define these outside of the Class?

Comment: You should create the Queue before you start using them, so yes, outside/before the thread Classes.

Comment: Why `q` is defined globally? I see official documentation also uses this approach. I would prefer to pass it to thread through `args`. Will it work?

Answer (score 7):

Here you go, using `Lock`.

```
import threading

print "Press Escape to Quit"

# Global variable
data = None

class threadOne(threading.Thread): #I don't understand this or the next line
    def run(self):
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        global data
        print 'hello world - this is threadOne'

        with lock:
            print "Thread one has lock"
            data = "Some value"


class threadTwo(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global data
        print 'ran'
        print "Waiting"

        with lock:
            print "Thread two has lock"
            print data

lock = threading.Lock()

threadOne().start()
threadTwo().start()
```

Using global variable `data`.

The first thread acquires the lock and write to the variable.

Second thread waits for data and prints it.

**Update**

If you have more than two threads which need messages to be passed around, it is better to use `threading.Condition`.

Comment: It's almost always better to use a queue rather than a global variable with a lock to send data from one thread to another.  You should start with a queue, unless there is a good reason *not* to use one. See the answer below from Gerald Kaszuba

Comment: @MarkLakata Can you please explain why?

Comment: @MarkLakata I would be interested to know why as well.

Comment: ..because the lock only has to be taken for the time taken to push an object reference onto the queue, (and pop it off again). There is no need to keep any lock while a producer is loading in the data in or while a producer is processing it.

Comment: Queues automatically take care of locking for you. Handling locking code yourself adds unnecessary overhead to your code (and maintenance/debugging nightmares).

Comment: If you have 2 (or more) producers and one consumer, queues are better. They guarantee that nothing gets lost. Both producers can write to the queue, and the consumer will always see everything. If you use a lock mechanism, the consumer may miss things if the 2 producers write stuff to the global value quickly, before the consumer can process it.

Comment: In Perl (for example, that's what I used to use), the only mechanism for passing data from one thread to another is with a queue. And it turns out to be the right thing to do... It simplifies your life and code in the end.

Comment: @MarkLakata If you have more than one producer and more than one consumer, you cannot use queues. Also, if you use condition, then no data will get lost.

Comment: @ATOzTOA If you have more than one consumer, then you can't use queues, of course. But assuming that your producer needs to run in real time and react to events on a fast time scale, you can't use locks or conditions on the producer, otherwise you will lose real-time data. That's a different type of loss compared to 2 producers writing to the same shared object, and 1 consumer reading from it. But it is still a loss.

Comment: @MarkLakata In my case, I have each real time event delegated to a producer thread, so I will never lose any data...